# Can Sublime Text 2 reformat C++ the same as Eclipse does?

Tags: c++, eclipse, format, sublimetext2

I am trying to transition from Eclipse (too heavy) to Sublime for my simple C++ codes.

So far I am quite happy with Sublime Text 2, but I am completely unhappy with the indent and reformat styles.

In Eclipse you just hit a combo of keys, `CMD+SHIFT+F`, and the code gets magnificently readable, I have to say that the standard `Edit>Line>Reindent` does not quite compete. So I have tried a couple of packages for reformatting but so far I have not found anything looking like eclipse. Does anybody know of one package that does the job?

Have a look at the three styles from 1. reindent 2. eclipse 3. the package

Cheers,
Roberto

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice plugin system [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) to do source code formatting.

You create a "style" definition for you project, for example:

```
# 4 space indentation
[*.py]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

And then it can be shared across supported editors (which are many), so that all devs working on the same project can share the same specs.

You can obviously also setup global styles for yourself.

Otherwise, for the actual auto-formatting, Sublime has a handful of plugins, like [this one for example](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter)

Comment: Thanks, "that one" is the first I tried. However is not the same as Eclipse. I mean is a matter of taste, and maybe years of habits on Eclipse ...